# Is it possible to install the same applications on Ubuntu Touch and Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch

I saw apps like Gimp running on Ubuntu Touch, but what about applications like Magic Draw?

Answer (score 3):

Most desktop applications won't run on Ubuntu Touch.  No Gtk apps, like Gimp, will run on the display server it uses, until Gtk gets a new backend for SurfaceFlinger and/or Mir.